# Is there something special about Wilkie's identity?

Tags: logic

In 1980 Alex Wilkie gave an identity $W(x,y)$ that holds in the positive integers with $1$, addition, multiplication, and exponentiation, but which can't be proved from the 11 Tarski high school algebra axioms. I want to know if there is something special about Wilkie's identity. More precisely, is it the case that if a Tarski algebra does not satisfy Wilkie's identity, then it can't satisfy any other identities that hold in the positive integers with $1$, addition, multiplication, and exponentiation that can't be proven from the 11 Tarski high school algebra axioms?

Comment: It's really hard to see what question precisely are you asking. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_high_school_algebra_problem#Solution) reads "R. Gurevič showed in 1988 that there is no finite axiomisation for the valid equations for the positive natural numbers with $1$, addition, multiplication, and exponentiation.${}^{[6]}{}^{[7]}$" -- isn't this enough answer? Thanks. P.S. Nothing special, just a counter-example to Tarski's axioms.

Comment: @Alexey it seems to me that the Wikipedia statement leaves open the possibility that any identity that holds in the positive integers but can't be proved from the eleven Tarski axioms implies the Wilkie identity. I doubt that this is the case, but I claim no expertise whatever in this area.